# How to hibernate manually?

Tags: hibernate

I can hibernate my laptop via `pm-hibernate` command without any problems. I want to achieve the same results manually. For this to work,

1. I need to take a snapshot and dump the contents of RAM+swap into a file (or `/dev/myswap2`), like:

   ```
   dd if=/dev/fmem of=path/to/memory.img
   ```
2. Resume from that file on the next boot, possibly by setting `resume=path/to/memory.img` option within GRUB.

How can I take a snapshot of RAM and Swap in order to dump them into a file (or block device) for hibernation purposes?

## Intention

I can

- take a snapshot of my whole filesystem while the system is running
- send the snapshots to a target disk
- replace necessary files (like `/etc/fstab`, `/etc/crypttab`, `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` etc.) to make the target bootable

So, when I unplug my USB disk, it's ready to boot my (or similar) computer, which cuts the [MTTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_time_to_repair) down to ~10 minutes in case of a disk failure. (~1 minute to boot and ~9 minutes to reopen my applications, rearrange the windows, etc. after login.)

My intention is that if I could take a snapshot of my RAM in the same way the `pm-hibernate` does and write it to the target disk's swap area, then I could boot into the exact same state of backup moment (as if my target disk is hibernated) in such a disk failure scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can transition by writing into `/sys/power/state` one of sleep states contained inside, es.

```
echo disk > /sys/power/state
```

Available states are:

- `freeze` (Suspend-to-Idle)
- `standby` (Power-On Suspend)
- `mem` (Suspend-to-RAM)
- `disk` (Suspend-to-Disk)

`/sys/power/disk` controls the operating mode of hibernation (Suspend-to-Disk).

Available options are:

- `platform' (put the system into sleep using a platform-provided method)
- `shutdown` (shut the system down)
- `reboot` (reboot the system)
- `suspend` (trigger a Suspend-to-RAM transition)
- `test_resume` (resume-after-hibernation test mode)

#### References

[Linux kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/interface.txt)

Comment: Writing to `/sys/power/state` will trigger an actual hibernate, is that correct? If so, I don't want to hibernate my computer during a backup operation, I only want to "simulate" it.

Comment: Try check ACPI code. From the reference: *"the 'platform' option is only available if the platform provides a special mechanism to put the system to sleep after creating a hibernation image (ACPI does that, for example)."*